# Subgroup of $S_4$ generated by $\{(123), (12)(34)\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I refer to the following problem.

> Determine the subgroup of $S_4$ generated by $\{(123), (12)(34)\}$.

In his solution to the problem the author makes the following claim:

> As $(123) \in A_4$ and $ (12)(34) \in A_4$, then **certainly** $ \langle S \rangle   \leq A_4$.

It is this claim that is of concern to me (**not**  the above problem). 
In particular, I fail to see how the implication

$(123) \in A_4$ and $ (12)(34) \in A_4  \implies  \  \langle S \rangle  \ \leq A_4$

is immediate or self evident.

What am I missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It follows from closure of $A_4$ as a group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, $\langle S \rangle$ is *defined* as the smallest subgroup (of a given group $G$) which contains $S \subseteq G$. Now there is no doubt that $A_{4}$ is a subgroup of $G = S_{4}$, and that $A_{4}$ contains $S$.

Comment: Thank you, of course... How could I have missed that :)